# Breadcrumbs not working

Tags: php, breadcrumbs

I use this code below on my site to process breadcrumbs,
The problem with this code that i am getting all the time the same hierarchy and not the true one..

for example: url is `hxxp://fakesite.com/A/B/C/d`
it will print:

> Home » A » B » C » D (its good but check the links below)

But the links will always be one level under Home page:

```
hxxp://fakesite.com/-->Home
hxxp://fakesite.com/A-->A
hxxp://fakesite.com/B-->B
hxxp://fakesite.com/C-->C
```

instead of

```
hxxp://fakesite.com/-->Home
hxxp://fakesite.com/A-->A
hxxp://fakesite.com/A/B-->B
hxxp://fakesite.com/A/B/C-->C
```

How can I fix it to have the right hierarchy

Thanks for your Help!!

```
<?php

// This function will take $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and build a breadcrumb based on the user's current path
function breadcrumbs($separator = ' &raquo; ', $home = 'Home') {
// This gets the REQUEST_URI (/path/to/file.php), splits the string (using '/') into an array, and then filters out any empty values
$path = array_filter(explode('/', parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)));

// This will build our "base URL" ... Also accounts for HTTPS :)
$base = ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';

// Initialize a temporary array with our breadcrumbs. (starting with our home page, which I'm assuming will be the base URL)
$breadcrumbs = Array("<a href=\"$base\">$home</a>");
$last = end(array_keys($path));

// Find out the index for the last value in our path array
$last = end(array_keys($path));

// Build the rest of the breadcrumbs
foreach ($path AS $x => $crumb) {
 // Our "title" is the text that will be displayed (strip out .php and turn '_' into a space)
    $title = ucwords(str_replace(Array('.php', '_'), Array('', ' '), $crumb));

    // If we are not on the last index, then display an <a> tag
    if ($x != $last)
        $breadcrumbs[] = "<a href=\"$base$crumb\">$title</a>";
    // Otherwise, just display the title (minus)
    else
        $breadcrumbs[] = $title;
}

// Build our temporary array (pieces of bread) into one big string :)
return implode($separator, $breadcrumbs);
}

?>

<p><?= breadcrumbs() ?></p>
```

Thanks for your Help!!

Comment: You mean, that the a-tags point to the wrong destinations? (e.g. when calling `example.com/a/b/c` the breadcrumb for "c" points to `example.com/c`? Then it would be, because of `$base$crumb`. `$crumb` is only the current one, but you would need the full path of all crumbs up to now there.

Comment: Why did you tag it with .htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, the problem is that within your `foreach` loop, you are always using the **current** `$crumb` only. However, you will want to know **all crumbs up to now**.

The easiest method is to introduce a new array called `$upToNowCrumbs`.

I have edited your code to include this array. Then you will not build your URL from the current crumb only, but from the new array containing all crumbs up to now (note the new method for created the `href` part of your `a`-tag using `implode`).

This is your new foreach loop:

```
$upToNowCrumbs = array();
// Build the rest of the breadcrumbs
foreach ($path as $x => $crumb) {
    $upToNowCrumbs[] = $crumb;
    // Our "title" is the text that will be displayed (strip out .php and turn '_' into a space)
    $title = ucwords(str_replace(Array('.php', '_'), Array('', ' '), $crumb));

    // If we are not on the last index, then display an <a> tag
    if ($x != $last)
        $breadcrumbs[] = "<a href=\"$base".implode('/', $upToNowCrumbs)."\">$title</a>";
    // Otherwise, just display the title (minus)
    else
        $breadcrumbs[] = $title;
}
```

Comment: @davidd: As you are pretty new. You can click the small green tick on the left to mark my answer as correct solution, if it works now. Then I would receive some points (and you too ;).